# DigitalOcean Ubuntu ffmpeg app stops half way thru rendering, "Killedpeed=0.0569x"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, digital-ocean

I have a node app that combines a bunch of videos together and it is working on Mac/Win10. I'm trying to host it on Digital Ocean and the app is working except for the final video build. The video is around 20000 frames and around frame 7000 the linux version randomly stops and calls

ect...
4211.4kbits/s dup=1 drframe= 7086 fps=3.4 q=31.0 size=   60672kB time=00:01:58.04 bitrate=4210.6kbits/s dup=1 drframe= 7088 fps=3.4 q=31.0 size=   60672kB time=00:01:58.08 bitrate=4208.9kbits/s dup=1 drKilledpeed=0.0569x

then ends...

The command I'm running is this:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" output.mp4
```

Does this have something to do with my linux Droplet being too weak in computer power or something else within ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Killed` means the process received a SIGKILL signal. It didn't crash as such (that would usually show a message related to SIGSEGV or SIGABRT instead) – it was killed.

If you weren't the one to use `kill -9` and haven't installed any unusual software (such as "CPU limiters"), then the only remaining reason why Linux *itself* would send SIGKILL to a process is because the system is running out of RAM and the kernel's so-called "[oom-killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory)" is invoked – which kills the process occupying the largest amount of RAM.

Run `dmesg` and search for oom-related messages. If you find any, then your VM is *definitely* running out of RAM when processing.

Comment: You are right, I updated to the next lvl Droplet and the app runs as expected. Thanks for the help.